# How do I change the variable type for a Entry() input to a float type in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

How do I change the variable type for a Entry() input to a float type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know how to use `IntVar()` or `StringVar()`, it would be the same but using `DoubleVar()`

[A brief overview](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Or, from [this website](https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_variable_classes.php):

> x = DoubleVar() # Holds a float; default value 0.0

If that's not what you are asking, I encourage you to be more specific and include your own code.